# Font works on localhost but not when I upload it

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have worked on an index page, just until the I decide how to build the whole website, and I'm having a small issue.

I'm using a google font, which works on localhost, but doesn't work when I upload the files to my webshost.

Can you help?

Here is the font download link - http://www.fontsaddict.com/font/pt-mono.html

Much appreciated!

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Epicenter: Moscow </title>
<center>
<style>
@font-face { font-family: PTmono; src: url('PTM55FT.TTF'); } 
h1 {
font-family: PTmono
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin-left: 8%;
 margin-right: 8%%
        border: 0;
        width: 84%;
    }

    body {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }

    #main {
        margin: 0 auto; /* in case you want to set a fixed width on this as well */
    }
</style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="logosmall.png" height ="120" width="500">
<br><br>
<h1><font size="3"> We are Epic Esports Events</h1></size></center>
<br><br>
<h1><font size="1">Epic Esports Events представляет новый турнир в дисциплине Dota 2 – EPICENTER: Moscow, с призовым фондом в размере $500 000. Соревнование пройдет с 9 по 15 мая 2016 года в Москве. </p>

<p>EPICENTER: Moscow состоит из трех частей. Первые два этапа будут проведены в приватном режиме в одном из столичных отелей (ссылка на Лотту). Плей-офф, который пройдет с 12 по 15 мая, примет одна из лучших концертных площадок России – Крокус Сити Холл (ссылка), способная вместить более 6 000 зрителей. Билеты на заключительную стадию турнира поступят в продажу в начале апреля.</p>

<p>В соревновании примут участие 8 лучших команд со всего мира, в том числе:</p>

<p>Evil Geniuses (США)
<p>OG (Европа)
<p>Alliance (Швеция)
<p>Team Secret (Европа)
<p>EHOME (Китай)
<p>Virtus.pro (Россия)

<p>Последние две квоты на участие будут разыграны в первом этапе соревнования между победителями четырех региональных отборочных туров. Во второй, основной стадии, 8 команд будут разделены на две группы, матчи в которых пройдут по системе GSL. </p>

<p>Команды, занявшие первые и вторые места в группах, начнут плей-офф стадию с верхней сетки, а финишировавшие на третьих и четвертых строчках — с нижней. Все матчи турнира будут проходить до двух побед (bo3), кроме супер финала, в котором победить надо будет трижды (bo5), без преимущества у команды, прошедшей по верхней сетке. </p>

<p>В мае эпицентром Dota 2 станет Москва, и это будет Epic!</h1></size>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the font is in the same directory as the html file? Also, are you sure the font name is written in all capitals? If your local machine has a case insensitive file system, but the server hasn't, that could be the issue.

Comment: I did a quick google to see if I could find the webpage, but all that turned up was this question. Even after only 8 minutes, Google has already indexed this.

Comment: What browser are you using? Two things to consider. First is that you will need to create more font formats as described [here](http://help.webflow.com/article/list-of-font-file-types-for-maximum-browser-support) . Also, in some cases, you will have to configure certain font types (MIME types) to be enabled on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you used Google Fonts. import this to your CSS.
Give it a try
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Mono);

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line inside your head tags:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and set the font-family in your body property:

```
body {
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-family: 'PT Mono';
}
```

Result: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t9zek4b0/)